# Why does new $class; return null when class_exists($class) returns true?

Tags: php, class, constructor

Sorry for the horrible question title, I wasn't sure how better to phrase it.

I have a class loaded and can verify this with `error_log(json_encode(class_exists($class)));` where `$class` is a string that contains the class name, `"JFormRuleDate"` in this case.

However when I call `$dateRule = new $class;` or `$dateRule = new $class();` then `$dateRule` gets set to `NULL`. Which I can verify with `error_log(json_encode($dateRule));`

The class inherits its constructor from its parent (which I can verify exists as above), and I could instantiate instances before I moved the file containing the class to a common library, but I didn't change the class so I'm not sure why it is behaving differently now.

The class is autoloaded but the cases of the file and class are both correct, I've checked. using var_export (can't var_dump in this context) I get `JFormRuleUint::__set_state(array(\n   'regex' => '^[0-9]+$',\n   'modifiers' => NULL,\n))` which seems right, and `is_object($dateRule)` returns false, and trying to use `$dateRule` throws `Call to a member function test() on a non-object` errors. And `!$dateRule` also returns true.

Never mind is_object returns false, I had that conditional backwards.

So the simplest test case I could make is:

```
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
$dateRule = JFormHelper::loadRuleType('date', true);
$class ="JFormRuleDate";
error_log(var_export(class_exists($class),true));
error_log(var_export($dateRule,true));
$date_rule = new $class;
error_log(var_export($date_rule,true));
if(!is_object($dateRule)){
      error_log('Couldn\'t load date validation rules.');
}//else{//commented for demonstration purposes
      $rec_valid = $date_rule->test(array('required'=>false), '10-2-2013');
//}
```

And the class is defined as:

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

jimport('joomla.form.formrule');

class JFormRuleDate extends JFormRule
{
  protected $regex = '^[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$';
  public function test(&$element, $value, $group = null, &$input = null, &$form = null)
  {
    // If the field is empty and not required, the field is valid.
    $required = ($element['required'] === true || (string) $element['required'] === 'required');
    if (!$required && empty($value)) {
      return true;
    }

    // Test the value against the regular expression.
    if (!parent::test($element, $value, $group, $input, $form)) {
      return false;
    }

    // bounds
    $parts = explode('-', $value);
    return checkdate($parts[1] , $parts[2], $parts[0]);
  }
}
?>
```

and my output is

```
[Fri Sep 06 16:06:08 2013] [error] [client ::1] true, referer: https://localhost//portals/admin-portal
[Fri Sep 06 16:06:08 2013] [error] [client ::1] JFormRuleDate::__set_state(array(\n   'regex' => '^[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$',\n   'modifiers' => NULL,\n)), referer: https://localhost/portals/admin-portal
[Fri Sep 06 16:06:08 2013] [error] [client ::1] JFormRuleDate::__set_state(array(\n   'regex' => '^[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$',\n   'modifiers' => NULL,\n)), referer: https://localhost/portals/admin-portal
[Fri Sep 06 16:06:08 2013] [error] [client ::1] Couldn't load date validation rules., referer: https://localhost/portals/admin-portal
[Fri Sep 06 16:06:08 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function test() on a non-object in /var/www/modules/mod_admin_form/helper.php on line 81, referer: https://localhost/portals/admin-portal
```

with `error_reporting(-1);` set, in addition to the above I also see:

```
[Fri Sep 06 16:13:56 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: date_rule in /var/www/libraries/metabolistics/validation/validation.php on line 18, referer: https://localhost/portals/admin-portal
```

Just remembered ob_start and friends, the output of `var_dump($date_rule)` is `object(JFormRuleDate)#1068 (2) {\n  ["regex":protected]=>\n  string(32) "^[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$"\n  ["modifiers":protected]=>\n  NULL\n}\n` and `var_dump(is_object($date_rule))` outputs `bool(true)`.

So eventually I just wrapped the loading and instantiating in a separate class which holds the rules internally and provides them via getters. So I imagine there was some scope issue I was not understanding.

Comment: You are using `json_encode`. What does `var_dump` show?

Comment: Please don't ask coding questions without posting your code....

Comment: Are you using an autoloader? If so, is it case sensitive? `class_exists` is not, some operating systems are.

Comment: please paste your php code... object constructor cannot instantiate into `NULL`, therefore your code might be overriding variable somewhere between object creation and your "verification"

Comment: also if something wrong with class loading, an error should be thrown so use `error_reporting(-1)` at the beginning of the code

Comment: Comments addressed as best I could.

Comment: Have you tried constructing the parent class? In your child class add a new method `public function __construct(){ parent::__construct(); }`

Comment: I had tried outside of the class. I thought that by not writing a constructor for the child the parent constructor would be used implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the file that was supposed to be loaded had a case issue which was only apparent on case sensitive filesystems, which my dev box was not.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't your last line be

```
$rec_valid = $date_rule->test(array('required'=>false), '10-2-2013');
```

since you assigned your new object to the var $date_rule

```
$date_rule = new $class;
```

not $dateRule

??

Comment: It should, yes but sadly that was just a typo here, not the problem.